# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reuse'

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu-14.04, syntaxnet

I tried creating a dragnn model Using Python 2.7, when i use wrapped_units.LayerNormBasicLSTMNetwork for tagger  error happe but when use FeedForwardNetwork，program run well ，as:

```
tagger = spec_builder.ComponentSpecBuilder('tagger')
tagger.set_network_unit(name='wrapped_units.LayerNormBasicLSTMNetwork',             hidden_layer_sizes='256')
tagger.set_transition_system(name='tagger')
tagger.add_rnn_link(embedding_dim=-1)
tagger.add_token_link(source=lookahead, fml='input.focus', embedding_dim=64)
tagger.fill_from_resources(DATA_DIR)
```

when i build train graph, as

```
with graph.as_default():
    hyperparam_config = spec_pb2.GridPoint(
        learning_method='adam',
        learning_rate=0.0005, 
        adam_beta1=0.9, adam_beta2=0.9, adam_eps=0.001,
        decay_steps=128000,
        dropout_rate=0.8, gradient_clip_norm=1,
        use_moving_average=True,
        seed=1)    
    builder = graph_builder.MasterBuilder(master_spec, hyperparam_config)
    target = spec_pb2.TrainTarget(
        name='all',
        unroll_using_oracle=[False, True, True], # train tagger & parser on gold unrolling, skip lookahead
        component_weights=[0, 0.5, 0.5]) # tagger and parser losses have equal weights
    trainer = builder.add_training_from_config(target)
    annotator = builder.add_annotation(enable_tracing=True)
    builder.add_saver()
```

---

when i runn ,error happend

> TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>       10         use_moving_average=True,
>       11         seed=1)
>   ---> 12     builder = graph_builder.MasterBuilder(master_spec, >hyperparam_config)
>       13     target = spec_pb2.TrainTarget(
>       14         name='all',
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dragnn/python/graph_builder.pyc in >**init**(self, master_spec, hyperparam_config, pool_scope)
>     173       # Raises ValueError if not found.
>      174       comp = component.ComponentBuilderBase.Create(component_type, >self,
>   --> 175                                                    component_spec)
>      176 
>      177       self.lookup_component[comp.name] = comp
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/syntaxnet/util/registry.pyc in >Create(subclass_name, *args, **kwargs)
>      180     """A wrapper around _Create() that curries the |baseclass|."""
>      181     path = inspect.getmodule(baseclass).**name**
>   --> 182     return _ResolveAndCreate(baseclass, path, subclass_name, *args, >**kwargs)
>      183 
>     184   baseclass.Create = staticmethod(Create)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/syntaxnet/util/registry.pyc in >_ResolveAndCreate(baseclass, path, subclass_name, *args, **kwargs)
>      164   while True:
>      165     resolved_subclass_name = '.'.join(elements + [subclass_name])
>   --> 166     subclass = _Create(baseclass, resolved_subclass_name, *args, >**kwargs)
>      167     if subclass: return subclass  # success
>      168     if not elements: break  # no more paths to try
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/syntaxnet/util/registry.pyc in >_Create(baseclass, subclass_name, *args, **kwargs)
>      129                   baseclass.**name**)
>      130     return None
>   --> 131   return subclass(*args, **kwargs)
>      132 
>      133
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dragnn/python/component.pyc in >**init**(self, master, component_spec, attr_defaults)
>      114 
>      115     # Construct network variables.
>   --> 116     self.network = self.make_network(self.spec.network_unit)
>      117 
>      118     # Construct moving average.
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dragnn/python/component.pyc in >make_network(self, network_unit)
>      141     with tf.variable_scope(self.name):
>      142       # Raises ValueError if not found.
>   --> 143       return network_units.NetworkUnitInterface.Create(network_type, >self)
>      144 
>      145   @abstractmethod
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/syntaxnet/util/registry.pyc in >Create(subclass_name, *args, **kwargs)
>      180     """A wrapper around _Create() that curries the |baseclass|."""
>      181     path = inspect.getmodule(baseclass).**name**
>   --> 182     return _ResolveAndCreate(baseclass, path, subclass_name, *args, >**kwargs)
>      183 
>      184   baseclass.Create = staticmethod(Create)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/syntaxnet/util/registry.pyc in >_ResolveAndCreate(baseclass, path, subclass_name, *args, **kwargs)
>      164   while True:
>      165     resolved_subclass_name = '.'.join(elements + [subclass_name])
>   --> 166     subclass = _Create(baseclass, resolved_subclass_name, *args, >**kwargs)
>      167     if subclass: return subclass  # success
>      168     if not elements: break  # no more paths to try
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/syntaxnet/util/registry.pyc in >_Create(baseclass, subclass_name, *args, **kwargs)
>      129                   baseclass.**name**)
>      130     return None
>   --> 131   return subclass(*args, **kwargs)
>      132 
>      133
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dragnn/python/wrapped_units.pyc in >**init**(self, component)
>      238     self._train_cell = >tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(self._create_train_cells())
>      239     self._inference_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(
>   --> 240         self._create_inference_cells())
>      241 
>      242     def _cell_closure(scope):
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dragnn/python/wrapped_units.pyc in >_create_inference_cells(self)
>     176     return [
>      177         self._create_cell(num_units, during_training=False)
>   --> 178         for num_units in self._hidden_layer_sizes
>      179     ]
>      180
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dragnn/python/wrapped_units.pyc in >_create_cell(self, num_units, during_training)
>      154     if not during_training:
>      155       return tf.contrib.rnn.LayerNormBasicLSTMCell(
>   --> 156           num_units, layer_norm=self._attrs['layer_norm'], >reuse=True)
>      157 
>      158     # Otherwise, apply dropout to inputs and recurrences.
>
> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reuse'